# creating a conditional column in a multi-level dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

level_2 = ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y']
level_1 = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']

data = [['a1', 2, 'b1', 4, 'c1', 3], ['a2', 16, 'b2', 48, 'c2', 78], ['a3', 10, 'b3', 12, 'c3', 34], ['a4', 114, 'b4', 6, 'c4', 1]]

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(level_1, level_2)))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

I'm very new to python, so apologies for the basic nature of the question.  I have the above dataframe.  I would like to create another 2 columns based on the 2 greatest numbers in column [A][Y] or [B][Y] or [C][Y] and then select the corresponding column [A][X] or [B][X] or [C][X].  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Original vs. desired]

I've tried argsort but haven't been able to figure out how to reference the correct corresponding column.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the prettiest solution but it gets job done (the main function is `Series.nlargest`):

```py
def fn(x):
    x = x.nlargest(2)

    a, b = x
    ia, ib = x.index

    return {
        ("Greatest1", "X"): f"{df_x.loc[x.name, ia]}",
        ("Greatest1", "Y"): a,
        ("Greatest2", "X"): f"{df_x.loc[x.name, ib]}",
        ("Greatest2", "Y"): b,
    }

df_x = df.xs("X", axis=1, level=1)
x = df.xs("Y", axis=1, level=1).apply(fn, axis=1, result_type="expand")
df = pd.concat([df, x], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    A        B       C     Greatest1      Greatest2    
    X    Y   X   Y   X   Y         X    Y         X   Y
0  a1    2  b1   4  c1   3        b1    4        c1   3
1  a2   16  b2  48  c2  78        c2   78        b2  48
2  a3   10  b3  12  c3  34        c3   34        b3  12
3  a4  114  b4   6  c4   1        a4  114        b4   6
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible option :

```
NBOG = 2
lvl1 = df.columns.levels[1]
lst2 = [[f"Greatest{i+1}" for i in range(NBOG)], lvl1]

arrg = (
    df.stack(0).set_index(lvl1[0], append=True)
        .groupby(level=0, group_keys=False)[lvl1[1]]
        .nlargest(NBOG).droplevel(0).reset_index(level=1)
        .to_numpy().reshape(-1, len(lvl1)*NBOG)
)

out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(arrg, columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(lst2)))
```

Ouptut :

```
print(out)

    A        B       C     Greatest1      Greatest2    
    X    Y   X   Y   X   Y         X    Y         X   Y
0  a1    2  b1   4  c1   3        b1    4        c1   3
1  a2   16  b2  48  c2  78        c2   78        b2  48
2  a3   10  b3  12  c3  34        c3   34        b3  12
3  a4  114  b4   6  c4   1        a4  114        b4   6
```